# How can you get element styles deriving from an external style sheet with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet

Whenever I use this type of code for javascript to fond the background color of an element, it always returns "".

```
<style><!--From external stylesheet-->
    #divexample{
        background-color:#4345C7;
    }
</style>

<div id="divexample"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var bgColor=document.getElementById("divexample").style.backgroundColor;
    alert(bgColor);
</script>
```

Comment: Are your styles loaded before the JS?

Comment: Check on [MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using `jQuery`. You could then easily get the `backgroundColor`:

```
var bgColor = $("#divexample").css("backgroundColor");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/h28zdhtc/4/

```
 <style>
  div {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 5px;
    float:left;
  }
  div.div1{background-color:blue;}
 div.div2{background-color:black;}
 div.div3{background-color:green;}
 div.div4{background-color:red;}
 </style>

<span id="result">&nbsp;</span>
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
<div class="div4"></div>

<script>
$( "div" ).click(function() {
  var color = $( this ).css( "background-color" );
  $( "#result" ).html( "That div is <span style='color:" +
    color + ";'>" + color + "</span>." );
});
</script>
```

For more detail see this:

http://api.jquery.com/css/